# Uncaught ReferenceError in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click the button to insert bbcode to textarea The console alert : "Uncaught ReferenceError: myTextarea is not defined". Can you help me solve this problem ?

I have a code:

```
$(function(){
function formatText(el,tagstart,tagend){
var selectedText=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);// IE:Moz
var newText='['+tagstart+']'+selectedText+'[/'+tagend+']';
if(document.selection){//IE
el.focus();
var st=getCaret(el)+tagstart.length+2;
document.selection.createRange().text=newText;
var range=el.createTextRange();
range.collapse(true);
range.moveStart('character', st);
range.moveEnd('character',selectedText.length);
range.select();
el.focus();
}
else{//Moz
var st=el.selectionStart+tagstart.length+2;
var end=el.selectionEnd+tagstart.length+2;


el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+newText+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);
    el.focus();
    el.setSelectionRange(st,end)
    }
    }
function getCaret(el) { // IE mission is tricky :)
    el.focus(); 
    var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
    if (r == null) { 
      return 0; 
    } 
    var re = el.createTextRange(), 
    rc = re.duplicate(); 
    re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
    rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

    var add_newlines = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<rc.text.length; i++) {
      if (rc.text.substr(i, 2) == '\r\n') {
        add_newlines += 2;
        i++;
      }
    }
return rc.text.length + add_newlines; 
}
$("elements").after('<form action="/post" method="post" name="myForm"><textarea placeholder="Comments..." name="myTextarea"></textarea><span class = "repbbcode" title = "Bold" value="b" style="font-weight:bold" >B</span></form>');
$(".repbbcode").on("click" , function(){
formatText(myTextarea,'b','b');
});
});
```

Comment: "myTextarea is not defined" Guessing that is the problem. Looks like you are missing it.

Comment: I have added it in name="myTextarea" of textarea

Comment: Yeah, that is a name of an element, not a JS variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".repbbcode").on("click" , function(){
    formatText(myTextarea,'b','b');
               ^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

myTextarea is not defined. There is no

```
var myTextarea = ....
```

in your code. You need something like

```
$(".repbbcode").on("click" , function(){
   var myTextarea = $("[name='myTextarea']).get(0);
    formatText(myTextarea,'b','b');
});
```

Comment: thanks you . It works ^.^ . But I think I have found the solutions in var textareaElement = document.getElementsByName("myTextArea")[0];

Comment: It is the same thing as my jQuery solution. lol You use jQuery, so why don't you use jQuery to select the element. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
formatText(myTextarea,'b','b');
```

You have to pass as the first argument a DOM element.  You can't just pass the name of a DOM element.  It's easiest to use `document.getElementById("myTextArea")` and then set `id="myTextArea"` in your element.

So, your textarea HTML would be `<textarea id="myTextArea" ...>`.

And, your code would be:

```
var textareaElement = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
formatText(textareaElement,'b','b');
```

---

If you want to get the DOM element by name, you can do that too:

```
var textareaElement = document.getElementsByName("myTextArea")[0];
formatText(textareaElement,'b','b');
```

What is different here is that `document.getElementsByName()` returns a list of potentially multiple elements so you have to reach into that list with `[0]` to get the first item in the list to pass to your function.

---

There are many different ways to do this (using name, class, id, etc...).  Usually if you are trying to get one unique element in a page, you would give it an id and use `document.getElementById()` or the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: Thanks . This works . : "var textareaElement = document.getElementsByName("myTextArea")[0];"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add    `var myTextarea = document.getElementsByName('myTextarea')[0];`

```
$(".repbbcode").on("click" , function(){
       var myTextarea = document.getElementsByName('myTextarea')[0]; // added myTextarea
       formatText(myTextarea,'b','b');
});
```